# Trouble creating directory

Tags: android, image, file

I am trying to create a directory to save images inside.

my function to achieve creating the directory:

```
 private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Fehler beim Erstellen der Datei: "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

I have added the permission to my AndroidManifest file:

But I get the following issue:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

The file path my app is generating:

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ImageDokumentation

Why is mkdirs() not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some little mistakes in your code, try this

Replace your first part of code with this

```
        // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME };
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But the code you gave me still lets my app run into the if where it says that an error creating file happened. Your code generates the same path.

Comment: run only the above code, comment other code & check directory created or not. then we'll go to file creation.

Comment: well, I have figured out what is wrong. The code works perfectly. I just had to set the permissions on the phone in the settings for my app. I can not understand why the permissions are not set by default to be activated